# How to Combine Attiributes in Weka in Prediction

Tags: tree, classification, weka, prediction

I study prediction on tennis match scores. There are two people; person1 and person2. Think person1 is A, person 2 is B. The dataset is:

Match Person1 Person2 Winner

1.    A       B       A

2.    B       A       B

You can see there are two matches and A and B won once. But the classification gives me if person 1 is A, A will win. If person 1 is B, B will win. But there is no home or away on tennis. The dataset is the same with:

Match Person1 Person2 Winner

1.    A       B       A

2.    A       B       B

You can see the tree will be different the beginnig. But these are the same datasets. How can I combine Person1 and Person2 attiributes? How can I explain Person1 and Person2 can swap?